# Storing JWT in client side and putting tokens in all the future request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, twitter-bootstrap, jwt

I have started using NodeJS with Express JS and PassportJS and JWT for User Authentication. I am able to authenticate the user and generate JWT Token. I am using Bootstrap for my front-end.

By using Postman I am able to get the token and put it in the next request header and it is working fine.

But how do I do this in HTML Pages using JavaScript?

- JavaScript to get response body or response headers
- JavaScript to set request header with JWT Token

Here is the snippet to store data in `SessionStorage`:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'token-abcd1234');
var token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
```

I have a mechanism to invalidate the token on `logout` by putting them in a DB.

Let me know if I am missing any pattern or missing anything.

**Note:** I am using login.html which has a form with a username and password. AJAX is not used.

**Login Page**

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Login</h3>
  <div class="jumbotron col-sm-6">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/login" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="password">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>   
</div>
</body>
```

**NodeJS Route**

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Could not log in user'
        });
      }

      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of posting this question, I had no idea about Frontend Frameworks.
Later I choose `Vue Js` as my frontend framework, things are working great.

All I was missing a Frontend Framework.